# Missing crash logs for iOS unit test runs in test result bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, fastlane

I am running a large unit test suite on CircleCI using Xcode 10.1, with fastlane executing the test run.

After some recent code changes, it seems the tests crash, once, and the test run is restarted, after which it completes. The crashes have happened while running different tests each time, but only one test per run crashes.

There is little to no useful output in the console about why the crash occurred. Based on [WWDC 2016 session 409](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/409/), I would expect to see crash (diagnostic) logs in the `xcresult` bundle produced by the tests, but I can't find them.

Is this something specific to Xcode Server, which they use in the WWDC demo? Is there some flag or environment variable that needs to be set to make these get saved in other environments?